# Public user profiles? Ruby on Rails + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-profile

How to make public user profiles? I use Devise and only have /user/. User can see only his profile, I want to make /user/user_id.

user_id - public user profile.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of writing a controller that defines `@user` as `@user = User.find(params[:id])`, assuming `@user` is what you use in your profile view?

Comment: I make blog aka twitter (for experience, I'm learn RoR). I'm user 1 and I want to see public profile of user 2 (photo, locations, bio, last messages).

Answer (score 3):

To make a public profile using `devise`, make sure you have a route set up like

```
resources :users
```

and make sure you have a controller action set up to handle the show resource.  If not, create a controller `users_controller.rb` and give it a class definition, along with a show method.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
end
```

Next browse to `/users/1` or `/users/2` (if you have two users set up) and you should see both profiles.  To set them to private, you should do a before filter in the controller action, checking the current_user id against the `param[:user_id]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a route on config/routes.rb file like below. And then implement your controller method and view.

```
  match 'show/:id' => 'user#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced, but I did it like this:

- In controllers create a users_controller.rb
- In views create /users/ typical views, for example `index` and `show` (of course define them in your controller)
- In routes add `resources :users`

You can simply add migrations to the users table, like

```
$ rails g migration add_birthday_to_users birthday:date
```

and show this on the users/:id page