# Specify link to profile page on devise(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First of all, I would like to say Im very noob on rails.

I read this question: [Public user profiles? Ruby on Rails + Devise][1]

[1]: [Public user profiles? Ruby on Rails + Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411795/public-user-profiles-ruby-on-rails-devise) and it's working. But I can't create a link to a specific user ID.

Here is my controller:

```
class UsuariosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using a forum gem, and in the post view file, I would like to link the 'post.user.username' ID to the link in its profile.

```
<span class="name"><%= link_to ".  "+post.user.username, usuarios_path, :style => "text-align: Center" %></span>
```

but it will go to the index, not to its ID (root/usuarios not root/usuarios/user_id)

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

`<%= link_to ". #{post.user.username}", post.user %></span>`

Also, keep your css from your html if possible.

Comment: It doesnt work, gives me an error:  NoMethodError in Topics#show

Showing /home/luca/monster/app/views/topics/show.html.erb where line #17 raised:

undefined method `user_path'

Comment: then go to your routes.rb file in the config folder and add `resources :users`

Comment: no problem, for these kinds of things i suggest you go through Michael Hartls tutorial

Comment: what should I do if I want to use another model name, not users? The problem when I user "users" it conflicts with devise.

Comment: Never mind, I just fixed it putting resources :users after the devise config in routes